# Interpreting a data stream in objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I am getting a stream from a live feed. It looks something like this as a mutableArray:

```
  "Columbia Heights",
    E04,
    "Cleveland Park",
    A05
```

The first line is a name and the second is a station code.

I need to turn this into a dictionary that is Plist compliant.

So the result in mind would look like this:

```
name:
"Columbia Heights",
code:
        E04,
name:
        "Cleveland Park",
code:
        A05
```

What I've written so far is this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *stationDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Name",@"name",@"Code",@"code", nil];

    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i < counter; i++) {

        // get names and codes for each of 3 fave stations
        //[stationArray addObject:[mutableFaveArray objectAtIndex:i]];

        NSString *tempName = [mutableFaveArray[i] valueForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *tempCode = [mutableFaveArray[i] valueForKey:@"code"];



        [stationDict setObject:tempName forKey:@"name"];
        [stationDict setObject:tempCode forKey:@"code"];

    }
```

I'm no longer getting an error, but I get as output, the same as my input.. I'm also only getting the last record..

```
  "Cleveland Park",
        A05
```

Updated Code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *stationDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Name",@"name",@"Code",@"code", nil];

    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i < mutableFaveArray.count; i++) {

        NSString *tempName = [mutableFaveArray[i] valueForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *tempCode = [mutableFaveArray[i] valueForKey:@"code"];

        [stationDict setObject:tempName forKey:@"name"];
        [stationDict setObject:tempCode forKey:@"code"];

        [stationArray addObject:stationDict];

    }
```

This results in the last dictionary entry being saved twice..

```
 {
        code = A05;
        name = "Cleveland Park";
    },
        {
        code = A05;
        name = "Cleveland Park";
    }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please better explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok. That's easy enough. What have you tried so far? Simply iterate the array and add values to the dictionary.

Comment: but I'm lazy. Seriously, I get errors that the output array is not plist compliant. I'll try some more...

Comment: Show the code and provide error details in the question

Comment: Will do. I'm actually almost there. I'll post code and result..

Comment: There is unicity of keys in a `NSDictionary`. So the desired output as to be a `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`, right?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes, there will be unique keys (name, code, etc), and an array of values

Comment: `NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < counter/2; i){NSDictionary *dic = @[@"name":mutableFaveArray[i*2],@"code: mutableFaveArray[i*2+1]]; [finalArray addObject:dic];}`?, with counter = [mutableFaveArray count];

Comment: Sorry I got the down vote. I'm trying hard to rework my question.

Comment: The "plist" output you show doesn't look like a valid property list.

Comment: I thought I had a solution but I don't. I've edited my question to show updated code. I get only the last dictionary entry. Help appreciated.

Comment: Could you show the value of `mutableFaveArray[i]` of each iteration?

Comment: Favorites/p1> ; data: {
    code = E04;
    id = nil;
    name = "Columbia Heights";
    order = 0;
    type = 1;
})
Favorites/p2> ; data: {
    code = A05;
    id = nil;
    name = "Cleveland Park";
    order = 0;
    type = 1;
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're only creating a single dictionary, `stationDict`, before the `for` loop. You then hit the `for` loop, which changes the values in `stationDict`, adds `stationDict` to the `stationArray`, changes the values in `stationDict` again, adds that same dictionary to `stationArray`, and so on. What you end up with is an array that contains the same object repeated `mutableFaveArray.count` times.

The solution is to either create a new dictionary at the beginning of the body of the `for` loop, or add a *copy* of the dictionary to add to the array. So, either this:

```
for (i=0; i < mutableFaveArray.count; i++) {
    stationDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    //...continue with the rest of your code...
```

or this:

```
    //...other for loop code precedes this...
    [stationArray addObject:[stationDict copy]];
}
```

Either approach ensures that each thing you add to the array is a dictionary that's distinct from the others you've added. As a refinement, you could probably speed up the code a little by using a non-mutable dictionary. If you have to create a new dictionary each time through the loop, you can create it with the data you want it to contain rather than changing the objects, so you don't necessarily need it to be mutable. Also, you can declare the loop variable inside the `for` statement, which ensures that it'll go out of scope as soon as the `for` terminates. Also, you can use Objective-C's notation for dictionaries:

```
NSMutableArray *stationArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i=0; i < mutableFaveArray.count; i++) {
    [stationArray addObject:@{@"name":mutableFaveArray[i][@"name"],
                              @"code":mutableFaveArray[i][@"code"]}];
}
```

You can further abbreviate that and maybe speed it up a bit using fast enumeration:

```
NSMutableArray *stationArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *fave in mutableFaveArray) {
    [stationArray addObject:@{@"name":fave[@"name"],
                              @"code":fave[@"code"]}];
}
```

Or you can let `mutableFaveArray` do the enumerating for you:

```
__block NSMutableArray *stationArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[mutableFaveArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))
    {
        [stationArray addObject:@{@"name":obj[@"name"],
                                  @"code":obj[@"code"]}];
    }];
```

That last one might be a bit faster, but perhaps a bit harder to read.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I really appreciate your answer. Both options work -- I chose the second. What a relief.  I can stop pulling my hair out.